# Using APIS's script tag in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to use the Yamli API in ReactJS. This API is used to convert your textbox text into Arabic. The API can be integrated with the following code in simple HTML CSS JS

```
<!-- YAMLI CODE START -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.yamli.com/js/yamli_api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof(Yamli) == "object" && Yamli.init( { uiLanguage: "en" , startMode: "onOrUserDefault" } ))
  {
    Yamli.yamlify( "searchArabic", { settingsPlacement: "bottomLeft" } );
  }
</script>
<!-- YAMLI CODE END -->
```

How am I supposed to implement this in my ReactJS Home Component.

Here is what I tried.

I included the  in my public index.html and put this code in useEffect Hook

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (typeof(Yamli) == "object" && Yamli.init( { uiLanguage: "en" , startMode: "onOrUserDefault" } ))
        {
          Yamli.yamlify( "searchArabic", { settingsPlacement: "bottomLeft" } );
        }
    })
```

But it is not working at all.

Here is my Home.js code

```
import React , {useEffect} from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import search from './search.png';
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Yamli from 'react-yamli';





function Home()
{

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (typeof(Yamli) == "object" && Yamli.init( { uiLanguage: "en" , startMode: "onOrUserDefault" } ))
        {
          Yamli.yamlify( "searchArabic", { settingsPlacement: "bottomLeft" } );
        }
    })

    return(
        <>
        <div id="searchBox">
            <div id="search">
                <img src={search} alt="search-Button"/>
                <input id="searchArabic" type="textbox" placeholder='Enter text here.'/>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="copyBox">
            <textarea type="textbox" placeholder='Enter text to copy.' height = "50" />
        </div>




        <Footer/>

        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

it wont work like this because Yamli is trying to control the searchBox from DOM directly. React will conflict with it.

What you can do is make the search component to not update form React. This way once it's setup React will not replace or re-render the input box

```
function SearchBox() {
  useEffect( () => {
   if (typeof(Yamli) == "object" && Yamli.init( { uiLanguage: "en" , startMode: "onOrUserDefault" } ))
    {
      Yamli.yamlify( "searchArabic", { settingsPlacement: "bottomLeft" } );
    }
  },[])
  
  return ....

}
```

then in your parent component

```
    return(
    <>
    <div id="searchBox">
        <div id="search">
            <img src={search} alt="search-Button"/>
            <SearchBox />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="copyBox">
        <textarea type="textbox" placeholder='Enter text to copy.' height = "50" />
    </div>




    <Footer/>

    </>
);
```